# Swift: Issue getting data from Firestore into an array

Tags: swift, completion

Completion Func to get data from firestore

```
struct User {
        let docID: String
        let firstName: String
    }
    
    var userArray = [User]()

// ...

//....


func getUserData(completion: @escaping ([User]) -> Void) {
              
               var result = [User]()
               
               guard let userID = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else {return}
               let db = Firestore.firestore()
               
              db.collection("users").whereField("uid", isEqualTo: userID)
               .getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
                   if let err = err {
                   print("Error getting documents: \(err)")
                   completion(result)
                   return
                 }
                   
                 else {
                    if let snapshot = querySnapshot {
                         for document in snapshot.documents {
                           let data = document.data()
                           let docid = data["docID"] as? String ?? ""
                           let firstName = data["firstName"] as? String ?? ""
                           let lastName = data["lastName"] as? String ?? ""
                           let email = data["email"] as? String ?? ""
                           let UData = User(docID: docid, firstName: firstName)
                            result.append(UData)
                            print(result)
                        }
                    }
                } //end ELSE
                   
                completion(result)
                   
               }
           
       }
```

Calling it here in viewWillAppear

```
 
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        
        getUserData{ (result) in
                   
            self.userArray.append(contentsOf: result)
            print(self.userArray)
            
            
        }
            
            
    }
```

Prints the following

```
[DaDoc.HomeViewController.User(docID: "avGhsRI1x0c", firstName: "Raul")]
```

**Question**

1. Why is "DaDoc.HomeViewController.User" This being appended to the array?
   i can't unwrap it with "!" throws an error "Cannot force unwrap value of non-optional type '[HomeViewController.User]'"
2. How can i access keys in here (docID, firstName)
   [DaDoc.HomeViewController.User(docID: "avGhsRI1x0c", firstName: "Raul")]

Anyhelp is appreciated!

Comment: take your struct outside from your class will resolve your issue

Comment: check it out and let me know if you need further assistance

Comment: @jawadAli  - Thanks for replying. still getting [DaDoc.User(docID: "avGhsRI1x0c", firstName: "Raul")]... can't unwrap it as well... should i move it to a separate file?

Comment: what is `DaDoc`?

Comment: yes move it to separate file

Comment: parent project name is DaDoc

Comment: `self.userArray.append(contentsOf: result)` instead ... use `self.userArray.append( result)`

Comment: still printing the same [DaDoc.User(docID: "avGhsRI1x0c", firstName: "Raul")]...

Comment: check out my previous comment

Comment: yea still the same unfortunately

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

Thanks for the suggestions @jawadAli - Moving struct outside the class worked

Even thought my result still printed as below

```
[DaDoc.User(docID: "avGhsRI1x0c", firstName: "Raul")].
```

I was able to access keys to add to values to a tableView like below:

```
cell.firstNameLabel?.text = userArray[indexPath.row].firstName
```